# In Ready Player One, did the race continue to be held indefinitely?

Tags: ready-player-one-2018

In the movie, there's a race between players trying to complete a certain quest.

> After the entire leaderboard was filled with players who had collected the first key (and beyond), did the race continue to be held so that additional players could continue (or killed avatars could start again)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Yes

In the book it says:

> Once the remaining empty slots were filled, the Scoreboard began to grow in length, to display rankings beyond tenth place. Before long, twenty avatars were listed on the Scoreboard. Then thirty. Over the next twenty-four hours, over sixty Sixer avatars cleared the First Gate.
> <sub>*Ready Player One - 0016*</sub>

This isn't elaborated on in the movie, however, you can see more than ten Sixers trying to complete the third mission. So logically, there would have to have been more than ten "won" races for them to get the Copper Key. Thus indicating the race kept occurring.

[image: sixers attempting 3rd challenge]

Comment: That was my next question...every single person in that queue had collected all the keys, then, right?

Comment: Not necessarily all the keys, but to be on the list (the scoreboard) you would need at least the copper key. Also if it wasn't held indefinitely then only those first ten that completed the goal would have been granted the ability to get the Easter Egg. That just would not be fair...

Comment: @Odin1806 - Also later in the book it talks about the "thousands" that were still clearing the copper key/gate combo after the jade key/gate had been cleared.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect the leaderboard in the movie was simply the top ten.  I expect there was another place you could look to see everyone's rankings.

> This is reinforced by the fact that IOI had hundreds of people who were able to attempt to fetch the third key.  Thus, they must have each acquired the first two keys, including running and winning the race.

Comment: Also answered in the book. The leaderboard expanded to show the thousands clearing the various challenges/gates.

Comment: The book leaderboard was different than the leaderboard we see in the movie...